# Running HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode on all references to Resources translations?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, encoding

### Long Version

In the web app that I work on, we put all our translations into .resx files that we then refer to by calling `Resources.FileName.KeyName` (as specified in the "To retrieve global resources using strong typing" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In some places we retrieve the value directly, but in a lot of cases we retrieve the value to be used in JavaScript, so we need to do something like this: `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Resources.FileName.KeyName)`

The problem is that there are thousands of these kinds of lines that need to be wrapped with a call to `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` retroactively.

There has to be a better way to do this rather than going through the entire source code and manually wrapping each reference to the resources.

### TL;DR Version

I need a better way of wrapping each `Resources.FileName.KeyName` call with `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()` than manually going to each reference and adding it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to come up with a true solution for this so I decided to solve this using regular expressions.

Now, the problem is that we are still using Visual Studio 2010, which has it's own subset of regex that is not compatible with a lot of advanced trickery, so assertions were not an option.

Instead, I just found all instances of `<Resources\.Thread.{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+}` and replaced it with `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode( Resources.Thread.\1 )`.

This can create duplicate calls though if you already had a few instances that were properly calling JavaScriptStringEncode, so unfortunately following that I had to find all instances of `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode\(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode\( {[a-zA-Z0-9_ \.\)]+}\)\)` and replace it with `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode( \1)`.

The lack of space at the end of the replace string inside the parenthesis is intentional for formatting.

There are other derivatives to sort out (spaces between parenthesis) but this is the baseline. After a few more searches to clean up duplicate calls, it was done.

Not my best work, but the best I could come up with short of upgrading to Visual Studio 2012/2013 and using real regex with assertions to do it all in one shot (which is obviously recommended if you can do it).